# dt/dd in same row alterates on line break

Tags: css

I have an listing build with `dt`/`dd` which shows key/value pairs in one line.

If the key is to long it will cause a line break, resulting in a wrong start of the next key:

[image]

This is my code:

```css
dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
dt {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
dd {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
.attributelist-striped .attributelist--key:nth-of-type(odd), .attributelist-striped .attributelist--value:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.attributelist-striped .attributelist--key, .attributelist-striped .attributelist--value {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <dl class="attributelist-striped">
        <dt class="attributelist--key">Matterial Armband:</dt>
        <dd class="attributelist--value">Gold/Stahl</dd>
        <dt class="attributelist--key">Matterial Gehäuse:</dt>
        <dd class="attributelist--value">Gelbgold mit Stahl</dd>
     </dl>
</section>
```

How can this be improved?

*edit to illustrate change based on answer of @Johannes *
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past it wasn't valid, but now you can wrap `dd`/`dt` key/value pairs in a `div`, which will let you clear those floats and simplify your CSS. Because the `divs` are block elements, the alternating background color for each row will be more uniform.

```css
dl {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}
dt {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}
dd {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}
.attributelist-striped > div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.attributelist-striped .attributelist--key,
.attributelist-striped .attributelist--value {
    padding: 5px;
}
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <dl class="attributelist-striped">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <dt class="attributelist--key">Matterial Armband:</dt>
            <dd class="attributelist--value">Gold/Stahl</dd>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <dt class="attributelist--key">Matterial Gehäuse:</dt>
            <dd class="attributelist--value">Gelbgold mit Stahl</dd>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <dt class="attributelist--key">Matterial Armband:</dt>
            <dd class="attributelist--value">Gold/Stahl</dd>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <dt class="attributelist--key">Matterial Gehäuse:</dt>
            <dd class="attributelist--value">Gelbgold mit Stahl</dd>
        </div>
     </dl>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `clear: left` to `dl` to avoid the described effect (which is caused by floated elements of unequal heights) and to force every `dl` to a new line:

```css
dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

dd {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.attributelist-striped .attributelist--key:nth-of-type(odd),
.attributelist-striped .attributelist--value:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.attributelist-striped .attributelist--key,
.attributelist-striped .attributelist--value {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="l-container" itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
  <meta itemprop="price" content="6.390">
  <meta itemprop="currency" content="&euro;">
  <dl class="attributelist-striped">
    <dt class="attributelist--key">Matterial Armband:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">Gold/Stahl</dd>

    <dt class="attributelist--key">Matterial Gehäuse:</dt>
    <dd class="attributelist--value">Gelbgold mit Stahl</dd>
  </dl>
</section>
```

ADDITION after comment and edit of question:

Actually, I would use a table structure for this, with the left field in every row being a `th` element (label) and the right element a `td` (data):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
th {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.attributelist-striped:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<section class="l-container" itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
<table>
  <meta itemprop="price" content="6.390">
  <meta itemprop="currency" content="&euro;">
  <tr class="attributelist-striped">
    <th class="attributelist--key">Matterial Armband:</th>
    <td class="attributelist--value">Gold/Stahl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="attributelist-striped">
    <th class="attributelist--key">Matterial Gehäuse:</th>
    <td class="attributelist--value">Gelbgold mit Stahl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="attributelist-striped">
    <th class="attributelist--key">Matterial Armband:</th>
    <td class="attributelist--value">Gold/Stahl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="attributelist-striped">
    <th class="attributelist--key">Matterial Gehäuse:</th>
    <td class="attributelist--value">Gelbgold mit Stahl</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks much better now. There is a small thing that needs improvement as now the line will not be in the same color (gray). I uploaded the changd screenshot and added to my question.

Comment: well, in this case I would put both in a wrapper element (div) and apply the background to that wrapper. (But in this situation you won't need the `clear: left`, since the DIV wil automatically start at a new line by default)

Comment: ...or use a table structure, using `th` and `td` elements in `tr` rows, inside a `table` wrapper (which actually fits better IMO)

Comment: please note the second snippet I added to my answer, using  a table structure as suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you, this looks as it would work as well. I am going with the div wrapping instead as I want to keep the already existing code in place.